# MySQL assign a unique value from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem that I can't figure out, I'm not experienced enough (or it can't be done!) I've trawled Google for the answer with no luck.

I have a system where I need to assign an ID to each row, with the ID from another table. The catch is that the ID must be unique for each row created in this batch.

Basically I'm selling links on my Tumblr accounts, I need to assign a Tumblr account to each link that a customer purchases but I want to assign all possible Tumblr accounts so that duplicates are kept to the minimum possible.

The URLs - each link that a customer buys is stored in this table (urls_anchors):

```
+----------+--------------------+------------+-----------+------+
| clientID |        URL         |   Anchor   | tumblrID  | paid |
+----------+--------------------+------------+-----------+------+
|     1234 | http://example.com | Click here |        67 | Yes  |
|     1234 | http://example.com | Click here |        66 | Yes  |
|     1234 | http://example.com | Click here |        65 | Yes  |
|     1234 | http://example.com | Click here |        64 | Yes  |
+----------+--------------------+------------+-----------+------+
```

All of the Tumblr accounts available for allocation are stored in this table (tumblrs):

```
+----------+-------------------+------------+
| tumblrID |     tumblrURL     | spacesLeft |
+----------+-------------------+------------+
|       64 | http://tumblr.com |         9  |
|       65 | http://tumblr.com |         9  |
|       66 | http://tumblr.com |         9  |
|       67 | http://tumblr.com |         9  |
+----------+-------------------+------------+
```

My best attempt at this has been the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `urls_anchors` (`clientID`, `URL`,`Anchor`, `tumblrID`, `paid`) VALUES ('$clientID','$url','$line', (SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS tumblrID FROM tumblrs WHERE @rank < 68 LIMIT 1), 'No')
```

Which works but keeps adding incrementally indefinitely, when there are only X number of Tumblrs to assign. I need the query to loop back around when it reaches the last row of Tumblrs and run through the list again.

Also i'm using this in a PHP script, I'm not sure if that's of any significance.

Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated!

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: Add some code. Did you try something?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that had some problems getting the tables formatted for the post, all sorted now. Apologies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `SELECT` query as the source of data to insert.

```
INSERT INTO urls_anchors (`clientID`, `URL`,`Anchor`, `tumblrID`, `paid`) 
SELECT '$clientID','$url','$line', tumblrID, 'No'
FROM tumblrs
LIMIT $number_of_rows
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7f87/2)

This will assign `$number_of_rows` different `tumblrID` values to the rows.

If you need to assign more tumbler IDs than are available, you'll need to do this in a loop, subtracting the number of rows inserted from `$number_of_rows` each time. You can use `mysqli_affected_rows()` to find out how many rows were inserted each time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but that query just inserts whatever $number_of_rows that I insert. Even if the customer only purchases one link.

Comment: `$number_of_rows` should be the number of links that the customer purchased.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! How do I include a WHERE in this query? Where the value is from another table? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394026/mysql-insert-select-where-not-working

Comment: Put it after `FROM tumblrs`. If the value is from another table, use `JOIN` in the query.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I'm unsure of the syntax for that.

Comment: It's the same as the syntax for any other join. There's nothing special about using it as the source for `INSERT`.

Comment: `FROM tumblrs JOIN otherTable ON tumblrs.someCol = otherTable.otherCol WHERE otherTable.col2 = $someValue`

Comment: Thanks for that Barmar, but it doesn't work. I have no matching columns that I can join.

Comment: What are you trying to get from the other table? If you're not joining on a column, you can just use `CROSS JOIN` and omit the `ON` clause.

Comment: I'm trying to read spacesLeft from tumblrs table, so that I can use WHERE spacesLeft > 0 in the original query.

Comment: You said the value is from another table. That's the same table, so you don't need a join. Just use that `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but it doesn't work. This is query: INSERT INTO urls_anchors (`clientID`, `URL`,`Anchor`, `tumblrID`, `paid`) SELECT '$clientID','$url','$line', (tumblrID+$counter), 'No' FROM tumblrs  WHERE tumblrID > 5 LIMIT 1

Comment: Why are you adding `$counter` to `tumblrID`?

Comment: I'm using it as a way to increase the tumblrID on for each line inserted, based on how many rows the user inputted.

Comment: But isn't it supposed to use an actual tumblrID from the tumblrs table? What happens if tumblrID+$count doesn't exist? My answer will select N different tumblrIDs and use them.

Comment: When I use your code, it inserts $number_of_rows for every link a customer buys. So if a customer buys 30 links they get 30* $number_of_rows. I should mention that I'm reading every line of input from a textarea, so this query runs inside a loop.

Comment: That's not how it's supposed to be used. If they buy 30 links, you set `$number_of_rows = 30`, then use it once.

Comment: It doesn't work, Barmar. I've just tried it that way.

Comment: It doesn't assign anything at all. No tumblrID.

Comment: That's strange! Is this possible with an UPDATE instead?

Comment: WIth an `UPDATE` you have to join the table you're updating with to the subquery that calculates the updated values. You'll then need a column to join on.

Comment: `UPDATE table1 JOIN (SELECT ...) AS t2 ON table1.col1 = t2.col2 SET table1.col3 = t2.col4`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Barmar, I really appreciate it, but that query just assigns the first tumblrID from tumblrs to every row in urls_anchors

Comment: You need a joining condition to relate each row in the target table to a row in the source table.