# MySQL insert select where not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm hoping someone can help, I've been trying to figure this out for days and Google doesn't yield the answer.

I'm using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO urls_anchors (`clientID`, `URL`,`Anchor`, `tumblrID`, `paid`)
SELECT '$clientID',
       '$url',
       '$line',
       (tumblrID+$counter),
       'No'
FROM tumblrs
WHERE tumblrs.spacesLeft > 0
```

The $counter variable is simply increasing by one every time. Everything works perfectly except the WHERE tumblrs.spacesLeft > 0 part. It returns no rows for some reason.

Here is the tumblrs table:

```
+----------+-------------------+------------+
| tumblrID |     tumblrURL     | spacesLeft |
+----------+-------------------+------------+
|       64 | http://tumblr.com |         9  |
|       65 | http://tumblr.com |         9  |
|       66 | http://tumblr.com |         9  |
|       67 | http://tumblr.com |         9  |
+----------+-------------------+------------+
```

The tumblrs table definitely has rows with spacesLeft > 0, so where am I going wrong? I'm using this in PHP if that's of any significance.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I feel a problem here: `(tumblrID+$counter)`

Comment: That part works fine, it's just increasing the tumblrID by one everytime. $counter is a PHP variable - that's all handled by PHP not the query.

Comment: What type is `spacesLeft`?

Comment: Jon Stirling - INT

Comment: Wait, there shouldn't be anything returned, it's an INSERT. Is that what you're getting confused by?

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not sure. So the WHERE won't work here?

Comment: The WHERE is applied to the SELECT and the SELECT is only used to get the values for the INSERT. If you didn't have the INSERT section, it would probably return what you expect. I think you're expecting these to be processes separately, but that's not the case.

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply. Is there any way I can grab the tumblrIDs where spacesLeft > 0 within this query?

Comment: Does PHP give you an error? If so can you tell us what the error is?

Comment: @TheoMoorfield Not really. To just get the data to use in PHP you'd just used the `SELECT.... FROM ... WHERE ...` part.

Comment: No the query runs fine. It just returns no rows, because the WHERE isn't matching anything.

Comment: No,  you're still not understanding. There are no rows returned because it is an INSERT statement. If you need the data in PHP, you'll need to do a separate SELECT query.

Comment: I understand Jon, I was replying to the other fellow. I was hoping there is some way around it though.

Comment: Ah fair enough, couldn't tell. There are ways of doing this in PostgreSQL, but I don't know of a way in MySQL.